# Implemented Oauth to generate token but how to validate that user has access rights are not for specific method?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin, access-token, owin-middleware

I have implemented following code to `generate refresh token` which i saved into database for future use.

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
        {
            return;
        }

        var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime"); 

            var token = new RefreshToken() 
            { 
                Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                ClientId = clientid, 
                Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime)) 
            };

            context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

            token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

            var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

            if (result)
            {
                context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

I want to `validate the use privileges without using asp.net identity`,

I have my `custom tables of user and privileges` .

> How can I validate and check whether user has what rights to access
>   all webapi methods or only selected from database?

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class OwnAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Your auth code

        // If you need base functionality
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Or you can try implement own mechanism based on [Action Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.98).aspx)